# Sorting <Player> ArrayList names alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
/**
 * Sorts the list of players alphabetically by name.
 * Adapt insertion sort algorithm.
 * You can assume that no two players have the same name.
 * Question T1. Adapting insertion sort for this method
 * could yield efficiencies relative to some other approaches
 * for some important special cases.
 * Do you agree and if so why? Write about 6 to 10 lines.
 */
public void alphabeticSort() {
    Player temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = players.size() - 1; j > i; j--)
            if (players.get(i).compareTo(players.get(j)) < 0) {

                temp = players.get(i);
                players.set(i, players.get(j));
                players.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've been trying and trying but I am having some difficulty trying to compare as you are unable to use `<` and `>` with a `<Player>` class `ArrayList`. We are also unable to use any `Collection.sort` imports.

A push in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare players by names, then compare the objects by their names:

```
if (players.get(i).getName().compareTo(players.get(j).getName()) < 0) {
```

If you're allowed to use `Collections.sort`, then the implementation could be a lot simpler and better:

```
public void alphabeticSort() {
    Collections.sort(players, (p1, p2) -> p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName()));
}
```

Comment: and you want to use Collections.sort() with a custom Comparator instead of coding the sort yourself...

Comment: It seems he's not allowed to use `Collections.sort`

Comment: Thanks for the help janos. Got it working now!

Comment: @copernicon1543 if this answered your question then please mark as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 Lambda to sort according to name in alphabetically order. It will be more concise.

Take the following code as an example -

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Person("seal", 25), new Person("tomcat", 32)
                , new Person("Alpha", 15)));

        // using Java 8 lambda to sort
        // you could use this portion inside your alphabeticSort() method.
        List<Person> newList = list.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> i.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // for printing
        newList.stream()
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    static class Person {
        String name;
        int age;

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    }
}
```

So your `` method may look like that will return a sorted list based on name-

```
public List<Person> alphabeticSort(List<Person> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> i.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```